# How to dynamically update a search term with React/Redux/Axios?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, axios

I'm building a small itunes application to fetch data from the Itunes api. I'm trying to implement the searchbar to make a relevant fetch to the server but I can't seem to figure out the correct props passed down from the Redux state. Since it is a small app I have used just the main App.js and index.js instead of separate folders for actions and reducers. My main App.js is as below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import Results from './components/Results';
import ToggleLayout from './components/ToggleLayout';
import AdditionalPages from './components/AdditionalPages';
import axios from 'axios';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const PATH_BASE = 'https://itunes.apple.com/search';
const PATH_TERM = 'term=';
const COUNTRY = 'country=es';
const ALBUMS = 'entity=album';
const LIMIT = 'limit=60';  

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
       <div>
          <Navbar
            searchTerm={this.props.searchItunes.searchTerm}
            onSearchChange={(e) => this.props.onSearchChange(e.target.value)}
            fetchITunesAlbums={(e) => this.props.fetchITunesAlbums(e)}
          /> 
          { this.props.searchItunes.itunes &&
              <Results itunes={this.props.searchItunes.itunes} grid={this.props.toggle.grid} additionalPages={this.props.toggle.additionalPages} fetchMorePages={this.fetchMorePages}/>
          }

          { this.props.toggle.additionalPages &&
              <AdditionalPages itunes={this.props.searchItunes.itunes} grid={this.props.toggle.grid}/>
          }

          <ToggleLayout
            switchLayout={()=> this.props.switchLayout()}
            grid={this.props.toggle.grid}
          />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    toggle: state.booleanReducer,
    searchItunes: state.searchItunesReducer
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {

    switchLayout: () => {
      dispatch({
        type:"GRID"
      });
    },

    fetchMorePages: () => {
      dispatch({
        type:"ADDITIONALPAGES"
      });
    },

    onSearchChange: (term) => {
      dispatch({
        type:"SEARCHTERM",
        payload:term
      });
    },

    fetchITunesAlbums: (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
        axios.get(`${PATH_BASE}?${PATH_TERM}${searchTerm}&${COUNTRY}&${ALBUMS}&${LIMIT}`)
          .then(response =>{
            dispatch({
              type: 'FETCHITUNESALBUMS',
              payload: response.data
            });
          });
        }
      };
    };

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

So my issue is with my axios url. For example if I hard code the url such as

```
axios.get(`${PATH_BASE}?${PATH_TERM}&${'someband'}${COUNTRY}&${ALBUMS}&${LIMIT}`)
```

the I'm able to fetch the results from the server but not when I insert

```
axios.get(`${PATH_BASE}?${PATH_TERM}${searchTerm}&${COUNTRY}&${ALBUMS}&${LIMIT}`)
```

and below is my `index.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import  { Provider }  from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import logger from 'redux-logger';

const booleanReducer = (state = { grid:true, additionalPages:false }, action) => {
  if (action.type === 'GRID'){
    return state = {
      ...state,
      grid:!state.grid
    }
  }
  if (action.type === 'ADDITIONALPAGES'){
    return state = {
      ...state,
      additionalPages:!state.additionalPages
    }
  }
  return state;
};

const searchItunesReducer = (state = { searchTerm:'', itunes:null }, action) => {
  if (action.type === 'SEARCHTERM'){
    return state = {
      ...state,
      searchTerm:action.payload
      }
    }
  if (action.type === 'FETCHITUNESALBUMS'){
    return state = {
      ...state,
      itunes: action.payload

      }
    }
      return state;
  }


const middleware = applyMiddleware(thunk, logger)
const store = createStore(combineReducers({booleanReducer,searchItunesReducer}),middleware);
console.log(store.getState());

store.subscribe(() =>{
  console.log("store updated!", store.getState());
});

registerServiceWorker();
ReactDOM.render(
<Provider store={store}>
  <App />
</Provider>
, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Any help is highly appreciated...

Comment: Hey, just confirming, on the line where you have this 
         axios.get(`${PATH_BASE}?${PATH_TERM}${searchTerm}&${COUNTRY}&${ALBUMS}&${LIMIT}`), 
You have not declared searchTerm anywhere or did I miss some part of your code  ?

Comment: It's the first property on the Navbar component in the App.js file...

Comment: What is your hard coded url??

Comment: an example:
`axios.get(`${PATH_BASE}?${PATH_TERM}${'iron maiden'}&${COUNTRY}&${ALBUMS}&${LIMIT}`)`
this will fetch the results and display them

Comment: @Kleo you can't reference the searchTerm on the the component. you have to implicitly pass it down as param.

Comment: @AndreeWijaya, could you tell me how? I referenced when I initially developed the app without Redux, so now I'm moving it to Redux and can't figure out how to

Comment: Gave some guides down here, do try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue lies with the search term, try to pass the value as a param,

```
     <Navbar
        searchTerm={this.props.searchItunes.searchTerm}
        onSearchChange={(e) => this.props.onSearchChange(e.target.value)}
        fetchITunesAlbums={(e) => this.props.fetchITunesAlbums(e,this.props.searchItunes.searchTerm)}
      />
```

and then the fetchItunes function as,

```
fetchITunesAlbums: (e,searchTerm) => {
      e.preventDefault();
        axios.get(`${PATH_BASE}?${PATH_TERM}${searchTerm}&${COUNTRY}&${ALBUMS}&${LIMIT}`)
          .then(response =>{
            dispatch({
              type: 'FETCHITUNESALBUMS',
              payload: response.data
            });
          });
        }
      };
    };
```

Comment: you were right about that, but now it will fetch random results from the server and not the ones from the searchTerm

Comment: `this.props.searchItunes.searchTerm` will have the searched text value by user, right?

Comment: correct and the state can be seen updating from the console/middleware

Comment: If `this.props.searchItunes.searchTerm` has the value of search text provided by user then how can it be fetching random results from server?

Comment: I don't know, I'm missing something on the code...an action probably

Comment: Can you post the code of Navbar? when is the this.props.fetchITunesAlbums get called from this component?

Comment: `<nav>
    <form className="form-inline">
      <input className="form-control searchBar mr-1" size="30" type="search" placeholder="Search ITunes..." aria-label="Search" value={props.value}
      onChange={props.onSearchChange}/>
      <button onClick={(e) => props.fetchITunesAlbums(e,props.searchTerm)}  className=" searchButton my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </nav>`

Comment: Can you try changing this onClick as `<button onClick={(e) => props.fetchITunesAlbums(e)} `.

Comment: I did, nothing changes...whatever input I put on the searchbar, always fetching the same pattern of results

Comment: That is because the `this.props.searchItunes.searchTerm` is not getting updated with correct search value.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this on the search bar

```
onChange={(e) => props.fetchItunesAlbums(e.target.value)}
```

And update your fetchItunesAlbums to:

```
  axios.get(`${PATH_BASE}?${PATH_TERM}${e}&${COUNTRY}&${ALBUMS}&${LIMIT}`)
```

Instead of saving the search term on app state redux. see if it works.